# Drl hierarchy issue

Tags: java, drools

**The hierarchy which we are using is like this :**

```
PersAutoPolicyQuoteInqRq
->PersPolicy
   ->Form
     -> FormName
```

**The drl generating is like****

```
@inputparameter( PersAutoPolicyQuoteInqRq$FormName$String)
    dialect "mvel"
    no-loop false
    salience -1
    when 

        $d : RuleData(agendaGroup=="PnCRule")
        persautopolicyquoteinqrq: PersAutoPolicyQuoteInqRq((persPolicy.form.formName == "Hii"))
        eval(isExecutable("New Rule-New Condition-IF",$d))
```

**I am getting an error while executing this drl :**

```
[Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: org.acord.standards.PersAutoPolicyQuoteInqRq.persPolicy()]
[Near : {... persPolicy.form.formName ....}]
             ^
[Line: 47, Column: 2] : [Rule name='New Rule-New Condition-IF']

Unable to Analyse Expression persPolicy.form.formName == "Hii":
```

**Please someone help me how to resolve this issue. It is not getting the hierarchy**

Comment: We need to see declaration and getter of field persPolicy in class PersAutoPolicyQuoteInqRq - please add this to your Q. Perhaps you'll have the same problem also in the classes PersPolicy (with field form) and Form (with field formName); so you better post these, too.

Comment: thank you laune the problem was because of getter field only.

Comment: Then: remove or writen an answer explaining the problem.